# How to perform a two-way linear regression?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, linear-regression

Given the dataset $\{(X_1, y_1), (X_2, y_2), ..., (X_n, y_n)\}$, where $X_i$ are matrices of identical size, and $y_i$ are scalers, propose the following two-way linear regression scheme:
$$
\hat{y_i} = u^{T} X_i v,
$$
where $u$ and $v$ are vectors of appropriate sizes. Errors are defined in least square, so
$$
\min_{u,v} \sum_{i} \left(y_i - \hat{y_i}\right)^2.
$$

1. What is the general, linear algebra solution for such regression, if there is one?
2. Suggestions on solving this numerically by computer with the extra constraints that $||u|| = 1$ and all entry in $v$ is nonnegative, given that all $y_i$ is nonnegative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting problem. What is motivation for such a regression? In any case, even at point 1. the problem is not linear. The minimized function is given by
\begin{align}
f:=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i-\sum_{k,l}u_kX_{i,kl}v_l\right)^2
\end{align}
and necessary first order conditions have the form:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u_K}=\sum_{i=1}^n\left[\left(y_i-\sum_{k,l}u_kX_{i,kl}v_l\right)\sum_lX_{i,Kl}v_l\right]=0,\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_L}=\sum_{i=1}^n\left[\left(y_i-\sum_{k,l}u_kX_{i,kl}v_l\right)\sum_lX_{i,kL}u_k\right]=0,
\end{align}
i.e. you get a set of quadratic equations for which you need a nonlinear solver. At point 2., in order to keep non-negativity of $u$ and $v$, you need even a nonlinear optimizer, which is able to handle inequalities.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The motivation comes from a biological question we are solving. Basically, there are two sets of individual effects (in our case, different cellular receptors and cell types), and their total effect can be represented as a product of two. This also reduces the number of unnecessary parameters to be fit (as the dataset is not that big in our case). I propose it to be a general question because I think there should be many cases where there are two sets of independent effects where the overall effect is just a product of two.

Comment: Did my answer helped you in your problem? Have you tried to solve these equations?

Comment: Yes, I'm still in process of solving these. I think there should be a solution involving matrix/tensor derivative which I'm working on right now, and I wish it can guide some useful constraint to tame this question.